# How to automate upload file with double click without using send keys in selenium java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, upload, dropzone.js

Trying to automate using the below code but not working

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

fileupoladbtn.sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/Images/zoom_out.jpg");

actions.dragAndDrop(fileupoladbtn, fileupoladbtn1);

Comment: Check this page if you want. It's pretty detailed: https://www.guru99.com/upload-download-file-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: without using send keys

Comment: This is not possible and the reason is logical. Selenium is not a system automation framework but a web automation framework. This means that can handle web-oriented actions. Double-clicking on a file that is visible inside a system window (Win, Linux, etc) is not a job of Selenium. I think you need to search for another framework or keep using the send_keys concept.

Comment: did you try Autoit as mentioned below...??

Answer (score 0):

what I could understand from your short described question , you need to interact with windows file upload which is not handled by selenium , you need to use auto it scrip and call that in your selenium script.you can download Auto it and SCiTE which is the editor.

below is the autoit file upload script  -

```
Sleep(1000)
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
Sleep(2000)
Send("{Enter}")
Sleep(1000)
Send("{Backspace}")
Sleep(1000)
Send($CmdLine[1])
Send("{Enter}")
Sleep(2)
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

It will be saved when you go to tools and compile it in autoit editor, note the name from here.

once action to popup file upload is done,  and Window handler to file upload is visible call above script.

### for Java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\AutoIT\\FileUpload.exe");
```

### for Python

```
subprocess.Popen('C:\\Handle\\FileUpload.exe '+File_path, shell=True)
```

More Details

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html